# protect an xml file on server

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, access-control

I read here lot of answers about protecting a file on apache server, some told htaccess is only for deny user access for files. For me not..

Using the following lines I cant reach the xml, BUT my php script also can't!

```
<Files sample.xml>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

So how to protect a file from users, so that my php script could access it. The file is in the root dir.

Comment: How is your PHP program trying to access the file?

Comment: I wasn't correct: my javascript code reads the xml from the url.

Comment: @subdesign: If your javascript can read your xml file, then anyone else too can read your xml file, and there is no way to prevent it!

Comment: @linuxeasy's comment is your answer.  If you want to protect your users from reading your xml file, you'll have to use a different method of accessing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a linux server, have a shell access to it, you change your file permissions to

```
chmod 0700 yourxmlfile.xml  # this will make it readable/writable/executable only by the creator of the file.
```

or in your .htaccess file, you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^yourfile.xml$ 404.html
```

where your 404.html could be either a page not found page or any garbage page, which will display as invalid url.

Comment: im on linux, and have shell access.. chmod 0700 makes the same, 403 forbidden. setting back to 0664 file is readable

trying your second suggestion..

Comment: @subdesign: If you want your xml file to be readable by javascript, you can't prevent anyone else from reading it either. All these suggestions were for preventing the reading of your xml file.

Answer (score 1):

If by users you mean people accessing your website from outside, you have several solutions:

The best way would be to move it out of the web root (if you can). That will surely protect it from outside access.

If you can't put file outside the web root, use a htaccess to protect the file by allowing access from the local machine only :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow From 127.0.0.1
```

I also suggest putting it in a protected subfolder where you could store all your private files.

Comment: Thanks. I put my xml into a folder, used your htaccess commands, but my javascript can't read the xml. Firebug error: 403 forbidden - You don't have permission to access /xml/obs.xml
on this server.

Comment: Well you said PHP first. Your javascript is executed on the client side so it has the same access as any outside user. If you want to read the XML with your javascript, it has to be public.

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect the user to a 404 page by adding the code below to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*)your_file(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
```

Comment: With this commands, I can't get the xml file from url (404 error), but my js script also can't read.